# Comparar las filas de una tabla mostrada con un while

Tags: php, while

Estoy escribiendo un código que muestra los datos de una tabla almacenada en una BD usando un ciclo While. La tabla muestra 4 datos que son el `ID`, `id_cliente`, `Mes de pago`, `monto`.

En un cliente el While me muestra 3 registros

```
ID       id_cliente       Mes de pago        monto
1          25                  06            15000
2          25                  07            20000
3          25                  10            10000
```

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de comparar los meses de pago de las diferentes filas, es decir, la diferencia de meses entre la fila 1 y la 2, entre la 2 y la 3 y así mientras mas registros haya.

para así hacer conocer los meses en los que ese cliente no pago, en este caso serían el mes 08 y el 09.

Les agradezco a los que puedan ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: Esto lo quieres hacer en una consulta directa o desde php?

Comment: Oye de la manera mas sencilla posible, pero preferiría desde PHP.

Comment: entonces pega tú código php para ver como lo tienes

Answer (score 0):

Veamos. Tienes una tabla `pagos` con columnas `id`, `id_cliente`, `mes` y `pago`. Supongamos que el ID es autoincremental así que podemos rellenarla con datos de prueba que replican lo que muestras en tu pregunta:

```
INSERT INTO pagos (id_cliente, mes, monto) VALUES (25,'06',15000);
INSERT INTO pagos (id_cliente, mes, monto) VALUES (25,'07',20000);
INSERT INTO pagos (id_cliente, mes, monto) VALUES (25,'10',10000);
```

Tendrías que hacerte una tabla auxiliar de meses:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS meses (mes varchar(2));
INSERT INTO meses (mes) VALUES 
           ('01'),('02'),('03'),('04'),
           ('05'),('06'),('07'),('08'),
           ('09'),('10'),('11'),('12');
```

Y suponiendo que tienes una tabla `usuarios` con un campo `id` en donde existe el usuario `25`, la siguiente query:

```
select meses.mes, 
       pagos.id,
       usuarios.id as id_usuario,
       pagos.monto
FROM
meses join usuarios on 1=1
left join pagos ON meses.mes=pagos.mes AND usuarios.id=pagos.id_cliente
WHERE usuarios.id=25
order by mes ASC
```

Te daría todos los meses, el id del usuario 25, y los pagos, mostrando NULL donde no haya pagos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya con eso puedes ver qué otras cláusulas ponerle (poner ceros en vez de nulls, o restringir qué meses mostrar, etc)

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8015/2)

Comment: Gracias amigo, tu aporte me ayudó mucho.

Saludos!!